# Java Reactor: Logging in Mono.fromSupplier() within another thread

Tags: java, logging, project-reactor

Why logging in Mono.fromSupplier()

- works if it executed in main thread(i mean entry point)
- doesn't work if it executed asynchronously

For example:

```
Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
            log.info("AAA"); //this will be logged cuz executed in main thread(entry point)
            //some logic
            return someObject;
        })
```

```
someMono.flatMap(smth-> {    //executing asynchronously
                    log.info("CCC") //this will be logged
                    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
                        log.info("BBB"); //this won't be logged cuz executed asynchronously
                        //some logic
                        return someObject;
                    });
                });
```

Comment: can you provide fully executable code, as a Java JUnit test? I can't really replicate your "it doesn't work" finding...